# Getting filename without extension in php

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to add a link to each slideshow image in joomla, but I've got stuck at getting the filenames from the photos without the extensions. 
This is the related code:

```
<?php
$imgrootdir = "templates/".$this->template."/images/";
if ($headerType == "0" || $headerType == "2") {
  echo '<img src="'.$imgrootdir.$myimage.'" alt="" />';
} elseif ($headerType == "1" || $headerType == "3") {
  $picDir= $imgrootdir.$myfolder;
  $picDir .="/";
  if (file_exists($picDir) && is_readable($picDir)) {
    $folder = opendir($picDir);
  } else {
    echo '<div class="message">Error! Please check the parameter settings and make sure you have entered a valid image folder path!</div>';
    return;
  }
  $allowed_types = array("jpg","JPG","jpeg","JPEG","gif","GIF","png","PNG","bmp","BMP");
  $index = array();
  while ($file = readdir ($folder)) {
    if(in_array(substr(strtolower($file), strrpos($file,".") + 1),$allowed_types)) {array_push($index,$file);}
  }
  closedir($folder);
  if($display == 'random') {shuffle($index);} else {sort($index);}

  foreach ($index as $file) {
    $finalpath = $picDir.$file;  
    // output
    echo '<a href="http://testcl.net46.net/index.php/''"><img src="'.$finalpath.'" alt="'.$file.'" /></a>';

  }
  if ($showControl) echo '<div id="slcontrol"> </div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all it is a best practice to use Joomla's built-in file handling functions. See http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package. The functions have error handling built in I think. Also see JPATH. You can use these functions to strip tags as so:

```
$name = JFile::stripExt($filename);
```

Comment: I've tried what you said, but instead of the filename without the extension, there is index without extension. Please help. My current code is: `// output
        $name = JFile::stripExt($filename);
        echo '<a href="http://testcl.net46.net/index.php/'.$name.'"><img src="'.$finalpath.'" alt="'.$file.'" /></a>';
      }
      if ($showControl) echo '<div id="slcontrol"> </div>';
    }
    ?>`

Comment: I'm assuming your href="testcl.net46.net/index.php/'.$name has the actual file name at the end, i.e. mypic.jpg. Please note that "/index.php/" is not a folder, it is a file itself. If your mypic.jpg is in the root directory of your site, try href="testcl.net46.net/$name"

Comment: It won't work either. Now every image has the link http://testcl.net46.net/index and 404s. The links to my pages are http://testcl.net46.net/index.php/link, that's why I put index.php before .$name.. Could you please point to me where I should put the code? I am doing something wrong for sure.

Comment: add echo "$picDir$file\n"; atop the foreach($index as $file) loop and post what is returned. I want to see what is being returned.

Comment: I posted it and got this: templates/a4joomla-autumn-free/images/sampledata/. It's fading in and out each time a new slide appears, but I got it from the source.

Comment: That string doesn't have an image in it. If did indeed add the echo "$picDir$file"; line, the file name should be echoed also. This suggests that your file functions aren't fetching the name properly. To confirm print the $index array out and see if its empty. If this is the case, the error is likely occuring in your while read dir loop.

Comment: How can I fix this? I replaced "$picDir$file" with "$index" and it printed Array, just like it printed that before.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I kinda fell asleep after fixing this. Turns out I just had to write $file instead of $filename in the line of code you firstly gave me. Thanks a lot for your help! You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: I've tried some of those, they won't work. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Where should I put the code?